# Using group by with order in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Query:

```
select "fightEventId", fe."from" , f.status
from 
    location_time_slot lts 
inner join
    fight_events fe on lts."fightEventId" = fe.id
inner join
    fights f on lts.id = f."slotId"
where
    f.status = 'CONFIRMED'
    and true 
    and (
        now() at time zone 'utc' >= fe."from" and now() at time zone 'utc' <= fe."to" 
    )
    or true and now() at time zone 'utc' <= fe."to" 
    or false and now() at time zone 'utc' > fe."to"
order by fe."from" 
limit 100
offset 0;
```

It yields this:

```
fightEventId|from               |status   |
------------+-------------------+---------+
           2|2021-07-02 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           2|2021-07-02 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           2|2021-07-02 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           2|2021-07-02 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
          17|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
          17|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
           1|2021-07-03 15:00:00|CONFIRMED|
```

What I need is to show those `"fightEventId"`s that have more than 2 `CONFIRMED` fights.
Currently all records are ordered in the right way, so the result I expect is:

```
fightEventId|
------------+
           2|
           1|
```

How do I do this? Every time I try, I get errors or the order is broken.

As for the DBMS used in the project, it's PostgreSQL but I wrote MySQL cos I'm pretty sure there're solutions that work with both.

P.S.

This query comes from the ORM I'm using, so please don't be confused with those `true`s and `false`s. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just use aggregation and `having`:

```
select fightEventId
from t
where status = 'CONFIRMED'
group by fightEventId
having count(*) > 2;
```

In your query:

```
select fightEventId 
from location_time_slot lts join
     fight_events fe
     on lts."fightEventId" = fe.id join
     fights f on lts.id = f."slotId"
where f.status = 'CONFIRMED' and
      (now() at time zone 'utc' >= fe."from" and now() at time zone 'utc' <= fe."to" 
      ) or
      now() at time zone 'utc' <= fe."to" or
      now() at time zone 'utc' > fe."to"
group by fightEventId
having count(*) > 2
order by max(fe."from");
```

Comment: Yep but it yields `fightEventIds` = [1, 2] while I need them in the same order as in my first table, that's to say, the second event should be at the first position and the first event at the second position. Cos the second event is going to happen earlier in time.

Comment: @one_tit_shark . . . Just add an `order by`, if you need them in a particular order.